# how to share image with text in flutter on whatsapp or else?

Tags: php, android, ios, mysql, flutter

I used this code to fetch images from the MySQL database and show them on the container. will you please guide me on how to share this image with text? Or what plugin I need to use.

```
        Image image;

        showImage(String image){
        return Image.memory(base64.decode(image), fit: BoxFit.fill,);
        }

        //show in Container

        Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: showImage(widget.product_detail_pictue),
        ),
        

        child: image = showImage(product.image)),

        it also show image but failed to share.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Share](https://pub.dev/packages/share/install) package.`

It allows you to share content from your Flutter app via the platform's share dialog.